# Partial String match on both side of the columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

[Code]

```
d = {
    'ID': ['1', '4', '5', '9'],
    'username': ['haabi.g', 'pugal.g', 'janani.g', 'hajacob.h'],
    'email': ['abi@gmail.com', 'pugal.g@yahoo.in', 'jan232@gmail.com', 'jacob@hoi.com'],
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df1)
```

[image]

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for idx, row in df1.iterrows():
    d = df1[df1['email'].str.startswith(row['username'])]
    if not d.empty:
        df = pd.concat([df, d])
df
```

Using the above code I can filter all the partially matching rows on **RIGHT side** column (i.e `email` => `username`)..

**Current Output:**

[image]

But I want the reversed matching as well (i.e `username` => `email`), as below

**Expected Output:**

[image]

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Just a note; *typically* iterating a DataFrame is an inefficient (and generally bad) idea.  This same task can be (should be) performed using broadcasting.

Comment: To accomplish the ‘reverse’ task, you’ll need to define a rule as to which characters are matched.  As you can see, the two examples in the highlight use *different* logic.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works. The reverse task requires you have some minimum condition to match on, in this case, three consecutive matches.

Hopefully, this gets you started in the right direction.

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {
    'ID': ['1', '4', '5', '9'],
    'username': ['haabi.g', 'pugal.g', 'janani.g', 'hajacob.h'],
    'email': ['abi@gmail.com', 'pugal.g@yahoo.in', 'jan232@gmail.com', 'jacob@hoi.com'],
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d)


df1['email_match'] =df1.apply(lambda x: x['email'].startswith(x['username']), axis=1)
df1['user_match'] =df1.apply(lambda x: x['username'].startswith(x['email'][0:3]), axis=1)

print(df1)
```

```
  ID   username             email  email_match  user_match
0  1    haabi.g     abi@gmail.com        False       False
1  4    pugal.g  pugal.g@yahoo.in         True        True
2  5   janani.g  jan232@gmail.com        False        True
3  9  hajacob.h     jacob@hoi.com        False       False
```

You can add a counting mechanism, to know how many of the consecutive values match.

```py
def user_match(x):
    name = list(x['email'].split('@')[0])
    user = list(x['username'])
    count = 0
    for t in list(zip(name, user)):
        if t[0] == t[1]:
            count += 1
        if t[0] != t[1]:
            break
    if count >= 3:
        return count
    if count == 0:
        return 0

df1['count'] = df1.apply(lambda x: user_match(x), axis=1)
```

```
  ID   username             email  email_match  user_match  count
0  1    haabi.g     abi@gmail.com        False       False      0
1  4    pugal.g  pugal.g@yahoo.in         True        True      7
2  5   janani.g  jan232@gmail.com        False        True      3
3  9  hajacob.h     jacob@hoi.com        False       False      0
```